# How is the thread identification counted and will it recycle numbers

Tags: c#, multithreading

I was wondering how the Thread identification works in .NET. Does it always +1 the last number and never look back? or if thread 5 stops and a new thread is created will it use 5 as it is now free to use?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the log file produced by our multi-threaded application, I hardly ever see a ThreadId > 40; almost all ThreadIds are smaller.

Typically, threads come from the thread pool: they get "recycled" after use. And numbers are used again, too.